# Wondering about Returning Errors from a Web Service

Tags: c#, error-handling, service

I have a web service method, this calls functionality that's pretty complex in a c# class library.

In the class libraries there are a lot of try-catch scenarios.

What I would like to do is... if an error is detected, I want to set the return value of the webservice to false, and abort the thread, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do a typed [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx)?
And then you can handle it on the client side like this

```
 } catch (FaultException<MyFault> fe) {
```

Comment: Never used one, but it sounds interesting, I will have to research it.

Comment: I marked your question as correct, having thought about it, it will work in my scenario because I can pass the app contextual information in the MyFault object... thanks!

Comment: public class FaultException<TDetail> : FaultException
 
Name: System.ServiceModel.FaultException<TDetail> 
Assembly: System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0